# createFileAtPath not accepting NSURL anymore

Tags: swift2, nsurl

```
    let singleImage = "current.jpg"
    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent(singleImage)
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    fileManager.createFileAtPath(path, contents: imageDataFromURL, attributes: [:])
```

`createFileAtPath` stopped working after upgrade to Swift 2 and now it gives the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to expected argument type 'String'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `NSFileManager` has no creation method that operates on a `NSURL`. In my code I try to avoid `String` for path usage and this is one of the rare places I still fall back to a path using the `NSURL.path` property

```
fileManager.createFileAtPath(pathURL.path!, contents: imageDataFromURL, attributes: [:])
```